# PHP : How to understand bitmask value of access from ini_get_all function

Tags: php, apache, apache-config

i'm start to use ini_get_all function to retrieve all configuration option on a shared host server. in the end i got this chunk of array :

```
[allow_call_time_pass_reference] => Array
    (
        [global_value] => 1
        [local_value] => 1
        [access] => 6
    )

[allow_url_fopen] => Array
    (
        [global_value] => 1
        [local_value] => 1
        [access] => 4
    )
```

The PHP manual just give descripstion :

> It's possible for a directive to have multiple access levels, which is why access shows the appropriate bitmask values.

so, can anybody explain about 'access' ? ans how to understand its bitmask values ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Would you have read [a little further](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.ini-get-all.php) in the "Return Value" section, you'd have found the [link to the change modes](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.modes.php) and what they mean:

- `1`: `PHP_INI_USER`: Entry can be set in user scripts (like with ini_set()) or in the Windows registry
- `2`: `PHP_INI_PERDIR`: Entry can be set in php.ini, .htaccess or httpd.conf
- `4`: `PHP_INI_SYSTEM`: Entry can be set in php.ini or httpd.conf
- `7`: `PHP_INI_ALL`: Entry can be set anywhere

Comment: wow, thanks. Frankly, i read those page (it's more like my eyes see it but my mind denied it)

Comment: As of today, numbers for each value seem to have disappeared from that page, so this answer was quite useful. Thank you.

Comment: @macl, I'm glad that it helped you. If you ever have that problem again, you can also print the constants and see what they are.

Answer (score 2):

**Correct values**

I looked it up in the PHP source code and found what you could define as your constants:

```
define('PHP_INI_USER', 1)
define('PHP_INI_PERDIR', 2)
define('PHP_INI_SYSTEM', 4)
define('PHP_INI_ALL', PHP_INI_USER | PHP_INI_PERDIR | PHP_INI_SYSTEM); // = 7
```

To check an access level from `ini_get_all()` you can do (using `allow_url_fopen` as an example):

```
$all = ini_get_all();
$config = $all['allow_url_fopen'];
$isUserLevel = $config['access'] & PHP_INI_USER; // PHP_INI_USER = 1
```

**For reference**

In the PHP's source code in main/php_ini.h these constants are defined as aliases of the Zend equivalents:

```
#define PHP_INI_USER    ZEND_INI_USER
#define PHP_INI_PERDIR  ZEND_INI_PERDIR
#define PHP_INI_SYSTEM  ZEND_INI_SYSTEM

#define PHP_INI_ALL ZEND_INI_ALL
```

https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/c8aa6f3a9a3d2c114d0c5e0c9fdd0a465dbb54a5/main/php_ini.h#L45 (lines 45 to 49)

The Zend equivalents are defined in Zend/zend_ini.h as follows:

```
#define ZEND_INI_USER   (1<<0)
#define ZEND_INI_PERDIR (1<<1)
#define ZEND_INI_SYSTEM (1<<2)

#define ZEND_INI_ALL (ZEND_INI_USER|ZEND_INI_PERDIR|ZEND_INI_SYSTEM)
```

https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/c8aa6f3a9a3d2c114d0c5e0c9fdd0a465dbb54a5/Zend/zend_ini.h#L24 (lines 24 to 28)

`<<` is the bitwise shift operator in C++ so `1<<0` = 1, `1<<1` = 2, `1<<2` = 4. `ZEND_INI_ALL` is the addition of 1+2+4 = 7.

Comment: I corrected the values in the accepted answer. I suggest you take out the part where you mention that in your answer. However, the rest of your answer is still useful. Kudos.

Comment: okay, did so just now :)